# Definir o ion-radio como required

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

Estou montando um formulário dinâmico usando o ionic2, porém os componentes de múltipla escolha não aceita a propriedade `required` como eu faria isso no ionic? O componente que estou tentando colocar a propriedade `required` é o `ion-radio` já tentei também com o `ion-checkbox`.

> Exemplo do código utilizado.

```
<ion-list radio-group>
<ion-item *ngFor="‪#‎option‬ of pergunta.lista">
<ion-label>{{option.label}}</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="{{option.label}}" required></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
</ion-template>
</ion-list>
```

Oque pode estar acontecendo?